# Shrink library jar using proguard but keep specified classes

Tags: java, android, jar, proguard

I want to shrink spongycastle core jar but keep few classes and their dependencies. I use proguard but I get jar only with specified classes

This is my config:

```
-injars       core-1.54.0.0.jar
-outjars      core-1.54.0.0-shrinked.jar
-libraryjars  /Users/abc/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar
-printmapping out.map

-dontpreverify
-dontobfuscate
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,
                SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

-keep public class org.spongycastle.crypto.BlockCipher
-keep public class org.spongycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine
-keep public class org.spongycastle.crypto.macs.CMac
-keep public class org.spongycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You mean the only thing that's left in the resulting jar (`core-1.54.0.0-shrinked.jar`) is these 4 classes: `BlockCipher`, `AESFastEngine`, `CMac`, and `KeyParameter`?